# VueJs 2 and Symfony 3 Patch Rest Request

Tags: php, rest, symfony, vue.js, vuejs2

My goal is to make a event request **PATCH**, with VueJs 2 that fires following:

```
// Link and body is defined and fine
this.$http.patch(linkUrl, this.baseTerms, {someKey:'any value'}).then(response => {
      console.log(response.body)
   }, response => {
 })
```

On the other side, that request is catched by Symfony 3 - FosRestBundle like:

```
/**
 * @Rest\Patch("/translations/update-base-delta/", name="update_base_delta")
 */
public function updateBaseDeltaAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $postData = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
}

// config.yml:
fos_rest:
    unauthorized_challenge: "Basic realm=\"Restricted Area\""
    access_denied_listener:
        json: true
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
```

The result of this is: Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed

Here is the Request:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:PATCH
Connection:keep-alive
```

Already mentioned the missing Query String Parameters and the Request Headers.
Could anyone hint me to a working example or tell me, at which part to focus on VueJs or Symfony?

Comment: double check the url you make request to in chrome dev tools

Comment: Request goes to:
/translations/update-base-delta/ and on the Server side:
@Rest\Patch("/translations/update-base-delta/", name="update_base_delta")
Both URL matches.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out what was wrong and how to implement all this.
 - The Request with VueJs 2:

```
this.$http.patch(linkUrl, {somePara: 123}).then(response => {
      console.log(response.body)
    }, response => {
})
```

// note here that Patch requires a preflight procedure (CORS) that sends first a OPTIONS request with following demanding header keys:

- Access-Control-Allow-Origin
- Access-Control-Allow-Methods
- Access-Control-Allow-Headers

**Response part**: the Server side has to follow also this preflight procedure. First, check if OPTIONS and requirements fulfilled -> send the mentioned Header Keys, second: react to the request.

Here is the Symfony 3 and Fos Rest Bundle integration example:

```
    /**
     * @Options("/translations/update-base-delta/")
    */
    public function preflightMyPatchAction(Request $request)
    {    
        $response = new Response(); 
        $response->setContent(json_encode(true));
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PATCH');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * @Patch("/translations/update-base-delta/")
    */
    public function myPatchAction(Request $request)
    {    
        $response = new Response(); 
        $response->setContent(json_encode(true));
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        return $response;
    }
```